# Python oneliner to remove tags from chuncks of HTML codes

Tags: python, html-parsing

I have a datafile with chunks of HTML code that look like this:

```
'<div data-schema-version="8"><p>Cat and dog</p> </div>'
```

or

```
'<div data-citation-items="cite" data-schema-version="8"><p>Car</p> </div>'
```

Is there a simple way to strip these lines from all tags getting the text only like `"Cat and dog"` and `"Car"`, simpler than using BeautifulSoup?